# javascript .eval() gives me undifined

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, eval

Here is my code

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 black">
    <% @unit.attempts.order("created_at DESC").each do |attempt| %>
     <p><%= attempt.body %></p>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 run">
    <div class="view-lines">
      <h2>app.js</h2>
      <%= form_for [@unit, @attempt] do |f| %>
        <%= f.text_area :body,class: "editor"%>
        <%= f.submit "Run"%>
      <% end %>
      <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
          var code = $(".editor")[0];
          var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(code,{
              lineNumbers: true,
              styleActiveLine: true,
              mode: "javascript",
              matchBrackets: true
          })
          $('.view-lines').each(function(index,item) {
           var v= $(item).find('.editor').val();
           alert(eval(v));
          }); 
             })
</script>
```

for example if I want to add inside the text area

```
var favoriteFood = 'pizza';
console.log(favoriteFood);
```

The result I got in the alert

```
var favoriteFood = 'pizza';
    console.log(favoriteFood);
```

I want to run the javascript code in my example in the alert it should be pizza

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish here, but for the purpose of just solving your problem, you could evaluate the commands first assuming that they populate a given variable name, and then alert using that variable name instead of the result of `eval`.  So in your case, something like this might work:

```
eval("var favoriteFood='pizza';");
alert(favoriteFood);  // will alert with the message "pizza"
```

If your expectation is that a user would put a separate command on each line you could loop through the lines and evaluate them all separately, like this:

```
eval("var favoriteFood='pizza';");
eval("favoriteFood += ' slices';");
alert(favoriteFood);  // will alert with the message "pizza slices"
```

Overall you should never blindly execute user input data like this, it's a big problem from a security perspective.  But I hope this helps with whatever you're cooking up today.

Edit : (responding to comment question)

In your case, instead of this:

```
alert(eval(v));
```

You could do this:

```
eval(v);
alert(favoriteFood);
```

Again this assumes that in your text area, you are setting a variable named `favoriteFood`.  If you want to remove that qualification I don't think there's a way you can do this with `eval`.

Comment: Thank you, but how can i take the value of the text area and alert it with eval() ? please fix my code

Comment: the value of the text area is v. i want to have alert with the running javascript that is inside  the text area

Answer (score 0):

You're not understanding what `eval()` does.
The `eval` takes as input the expression and returns the value of the last expression:

```js
console.log(eval("2+2")) // -> 4
console.log(eval("Math.pow(2, 10)")) // -> 1024
console.log(eval("let x = 100; x - 1")) // -> 99
```

`console.log()` is not changed inside the `eval()`. It does the same as in the normal code.

#### OK, but what if I want `console.log()`?

You can redefine `console` and `console.log()`:

```js
function executeCode(code) {
  let logs = []; // Logs array
  // Redefine console
  let console = {
    log(...args) { // We can pass as many args as we want
      logs.push(args);
    }
  }
  // Eval the code
  eval(code);
  // Return the logs
  return logs;
}

// Demos
console.log(executeCode('console.log("Hello, world!")'))
console.log(executeCode('let x = 5; console.log("X is", x)'))
```

#### Note what `eval` is evil

```js
let password = "1234"; // An important variable
let login = "vasya" // Another one

// Execute code
function executeCode(code) {
  let logs = []; // Logs array
  // Redefine console
  let console = {
    log(...args) { // We can pass as many args as we want
      logs.push(args);
    }
  }
  // Eval the code
  eval(code);
  // Return the logs
  return logs;
}

// Code may be not yours, as example shared to you
console.log(executeCode('console.log("Got your password: ", password)')) // Code can access to almost anything
console.log(executeCode('login = "abcdef"')) // And can modify everything
console.log("INFO: Login is", login)
// Or it can redirect you
// console.log(executeCode('window.location.href = "example.com"'))
```

Of course there are some ways to secure this, and if you want — I can add them